# How to set nested DIV height same as container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please find my code fragment as below:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:Aqua">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background-color:Yellow">Navigation</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make the height of `<div>` same as the content growth in `<td>`? I tried to set height=100% or AUTO in `<div>` and `<td>`, but it doesn't fix the problem.

I know it can be fix by using jQuery/JavaScript to get the height of content and set on the `<div>`, for example:

```
$(".divClass").height($(".contentClass").height());
```

but my content will be collapse and expanse upon user actions, so I looking for better fix. the solution has to be cross browser compatible for IE 6 to IE 10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: do you want your final table to look something like http://jsfiddle.net/VmrBB/?

Comment: also the jquery solution which you have is good. when the user performs an action that changes the layout you can call the same code (probably through a function?) once more.

Comment: is there a CSS solution only? cause I tried to minimize the scripting

Comment: This looks like a misuse of tables (tables should only be used for expressing tabular data, not for layout purposes).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly with HTML/CSS

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:Aqua">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span style="height:100%; display:inline-block; width: 100%; background-color:Yellow">
                Navigation
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I wonder this is the solution for IE? I tried and it doesnt work as per expected

Answer (score 1):

Try using `height:inherit;` :) worked for me :)

[JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/WmYzc/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="foo2">
        Foo2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.foo {
    height: 100px; /*try changing this */
    background-color: yellow; /*it wont show*/
}

.foo2 {
    height: inherit;
    background-color: green; /*it will show*/
}
```

Comment: the context is within a table, although a neat solution, it will not work in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/gdR7e/

Comment: I refer to solution of nested div in td, not nested div in div